Osculator plane as limit of planes
I have seen this problem on past years notes of my Differential geometry course and I am trying to do it:

Let $I \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ an open interval and $\alpha \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty} (I ; \Bbb{R})$ an arclenght parametrized curve. Given $s_0 \in I$ with $\kappa_\alpha (s_0) > 0$ , the osculator plane on $s_0$ is the limit of the planes containing $\alpha(s_0), \alpha (s_0 + h)$ and $\alpha (s_0 + k)$ when $h,k \rightarrow 0$ .

Let $\pi_O$ the osculator plane at $s_0$, that is $\pi_O = \{ p \in \Bbb{R}^3 \, | \, \langle p - \alpha (s_0) , B_\alpha (s_0) \rangle = 0 \}$ . For every $h, k \in \Bbb{R}$, denote $\pi (h,k)$ the plane containing $\alpha(s_0), \alpha (s_0 + h)$ and $\alpha (s_0 + k)$, in other words: $$\pi(h,k) = \{ p \in \Bbb{R}^3 | \det ( p - \alpha(s_0) , \alpha(s_0 + h) - \alpha(s_0), \alpha(s_0 + k) - \alpha(s_0)) = 0 \} = \{ p \in \Bbb{R}^3 \, | \, \langle p - \alpha (s_0) , [\alpha(s_0 + h) - \alpha(s_0)] \times [\alpha(s_0 + k) - \alpha(s_0)] \rangle = 0 \}$$
My idea was to prove that $\lim_{h,k \rightarrow 0} [\alpha(s_0 + h) - \alpha(s_0)] \times [\alpha(s_0 + k) - \alpha(s_0)]  = B_\alpha (s_0)$ or $\lim_{h,k \rightarrow 0} [\alpha(s_0 + h) - \alpha(s_0)] \times [\alpha(s_0 + k) - \alpha(s_0)]  = \alpha'(s_0) \times \alpha''(s_0)$ what would be enough to finish. The problem is that I do not see how to prove it, I have tried to make Taylor Expansion of order 3 but it does not seem to work, so any advice would be appreciated.
The Taylor Expansion for $d \in \{h,k\}$ is:
$$\alpha (s_0 + d) = \alpha (s_0) + d \alpha'(s_0) + \frac{d^2}{2} \alpha'' (s_0) + O(h^3) \implies \alpha (s_0 + d) - \alpha (s_0) = d \alpha'(s_0) + \frac{d^2}{2} \alpha'' (s_0) + O(d^3) $$
Then, $$[ \alpha (s_0 + h) - \alpha (s_0) ] \times [ \alpha (s_0 + k) - \alpha (s_0) ] = [ h \alpha'(s_0) + \frac{h^2}{2} \alpha'' (s_0) + O(h^3) ] \times [ k \alpha'(s_0) + \frac{k^2}{2} \alpha'' (s_0) + O(k^3) ] = \frac{hk^2 - h^2 k}{2} \alpha'(s_0) \times \alpha'' (s_0) + O(h^3, k^3) $$
which tends to $0$ when $h,k \rightarrow 0$ .
Note that $\frac{[ \alpha (s_0 + h) - \alpha (s_0) ] \times [ \alpha (s_0 + k) - \alpha (s_0) ]}{hk} = \frac{k - h}{2} \alpha'(s_0) \times \alpha'' (s_0) + O(h^2, k^2)$ which also tends to $0$.

The limit of the cross product will be $0$. You need to divide by $hk$, no?

@TedShifrin But that should tend to $\alpha' (s_0) \times \alpha' (s_0)$ which is also $0$, right?

OK, so now use the Taylor expansion and get the $T\times N$ terms.

@TedShifrin I have added it, but, as I said on the post, it does not seem to help.

You care about the limiting direction of that vector when $h\ne k$. Of course the vector itself approaches $0$.

@TedShifrin Sorry, I do not understand, what do you mean by limiting direction ?

You should be considering the unit vector $v/|v|$.

@TedShifrin Do you mean $\frac{ [ \alpha (s_0 + h) - \alpha (s_0) ] \times [ \alpha (s_0 + k) - \alpha (s_0) ] }{\lVert [ \alpha (s_0 + h) - \alpha (s_0) ] \times [ \alpha (s_0 + k) - \alpha (s_0) ] \rVert}$ ?
